# Simple query issue with multiple tables and mismatching IDs

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble with a simple MySQL Query.
Here is the query:

```
SELECT distinct e.E_CODE, s.S_CODE, p.P_ID, p.P_NAME, p.P_FIRSTNAME, p.P_STATUS, e.E_BOSS, tp.TP_TITLE
from event_participation ep, worker p, type_participation tp, event e, section s
where ep.P_ID = p.P_ID
and s.S_ID = e.S_ID
and ep.TP_ID = tp.TP_ID
and e.E_CODE = ep.E_CODE
```

The problem is that ep.TP_ID sometimes has a value set to zero while tp.TP_ID has nothing with a zero ID. It's auto-increment and starts at 1 and so on.

The result is obviously that this query does not return records when the ep.TP_ID = 0 and there is no match in tp.TP_ID.

So I'm trying to figure out a way to get those results in there anyway. I was thinking of using a LEFT JOIN statement but couldn't figure out a proper way to insert it into the query.

Any advice on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Switch to using proper join syntax, and all your problems will miraculously disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I advice you to use some general type for event_participation records without type; But, unless to take that decision, supposing you want to get all matching records between all tables but also get results with no type, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.E_CODE, s.S_CODE, p.P_ID, p.P_NAME, p.P_FIRSTNAME, p.P_STATUS, e.E_BOSS, tp.TP_TITLE
    FROM event_participation ep 
JOIN worker p ON (ep.P_ID = p.P_ID) 
JOIN event e ON (e.E_CODE = ep.E_CODE) 
JOIN section s ON (s.S_ID = e.S_ID) 
LEFT JOIN type_participation tp ON (ep.TP_ID = tp.TP_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.E_CODE
              , s.S_CODE
              , p.P_ID
              , p.P_NAME
              , p.P_FIRSTNAME
              , p.P_STATUS
              , e.E_BOSS
              , tp.TP_TITLE
           FROM event_participation ep
           JOIN worker p
             ON p.P_ID = ep.P_ID 
           JOIN event e
             ON e.E_CODE = ep.E_CODE
           JOIN section s
             ON s.S_ID = e.S_ID
           LEFT
           JOIN type_participation tp
             ON tp.TP_ID = ep.TP_ID;
```